# Open-source OCR package that can handle unknown characters?

Tags: character-encoding, ocr

I want to find a (preferably) open-source OCR package (for any OS) that is capable of handling a new character set.

The language is Latin, but with some scribal abbreviations, about 10 different abbreviations that aren't in Unicode.

The text has been printed using specially-developed fonts, and I have high-res images of the text.

I'm assuming some training is going to be needed, first to map the scribal abbreviations to ASCII, and then presumably corpus-specific training for the software to learn where the abbreviations tend to appear within words.

Could anyone recommend a (preferably) open-source package capable of handling this?

Comment: There are not many open source OCR packages around. If Tesseract doesn't cut it for you then you probably need to check out the commercial options.

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no library (free or commercial) that can be used as-is for what you describe (a language with characters not representable by Unicode) ... BUT as a good starting point there is an opensource OCR called [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) which you could take and modify for your special scenario... another interesting base could be [OCROpus](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/)... but beware: this will mean lots of work.